# how to recursion this string variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, recursion

I have read the example of factorial in recursion code, but I wonder to know about another example as well, I do love to hear for explaining this case to know a bit of recursion,

```js
function rec(deleteNum) {
    var tempNum = ""
    var tempStr = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < deleteNum.length; i++) {
        if (deleteNum[i] === "0" || deleteNum[i] === "1" || deleteNum[i] === "2" || deleteNum[i] === "3" || deleteNum[i] === "4" || deleteNum[i] === "5" || deleteNum[i] === "6" || deleteNum[i] === "7" || deleteNum[i] === "8" || deleteNum[i] === "9") {
            tempNum += deleteNum[i]
        } else {
            tempStr += deleteNum[i]
        }
    }
    return tempStr
}

console.log(rec("test3yyy33333"))
console.log(rec("e79898080xampl222e"))
```

how to check the string in recursion to get the result like the above without using `for loop`

i want the outputsame like above

Comment: what is the expected output from rec()?

Comment: same like result code above @NitishNarang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an exit condition, for example if you get an empty string, return an empty string.

Then you need a check if the first character is a digit, then return a recursion with a slice from the second character.

Without check, return the first character and a recusion call of the rest of the string.

```js
function rec(string) {
    if (string === '') return '';
    if (string[0] >= '0' && string[0] <= '9') return rec(string.slice(1));
    return string[0] + rec(string.slice(1));
}

console.log(rec("test3yyy33333"))
console.log(rec("e79898080xampl222e"))
```

A compact verion of taking the first and last digit of a string and return either this value if odd or zero. Then check the inner digits and proceed until no, one or two digits are left.

For strings, who are longer than two digits, call the function again with splitted parts.

```js
function oddPairFirstLast(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    if (value.length === 0) return 0;
    if (value.length === 1) return +(value + 1);
    if (value.length === 2) return value % 2 && +value;
   return oddPairFirstLast(value.slice(0, 1) + value.slice(-1)) + oddPairFirstLast(value.slice(1, -1));
}

console.log(oddPairFirstLast(2345));  // 25 
console.log(oddPairFirstLast(2335));  // 58 
console.log(oddPairFirstLast(23351)); // 87 
console.log(oddPairFirstLast(42548)); // 51
```

Comment: could we find modules in recursion(sting) ? @nina , did we just check it by string.slice as well?

Comment: what do you mean with *"modules"*?

Comment: i do not understand, why 12 and 19?

Comment: if you like to get two values, you could slice them from the string, but would not change the recursion, because it contains at least two parts, the exit condition and the part with some changes and the recursive call.

Comment: should we slice them from ```.slice(2)``` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183540/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-zr-classic).

Answer (score 1):

In case of without recursion, you can filter every character and check if character is not number

```js
function rec(str) {
   return [...str].filter(d => !Number.isInteger(+d)).join('')
}

console.log(rec("test3yyy33333"))
console.log(rec("e79898080xampl222e"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use follwoing recursive function to achieve your goal:

```js
    function rec(deleteNum){
        if(deleteNum){
            if(deleteNum.length === 1){
                if(isNaN(deleteNum)){
                    return deleteNum;
                }else{
                    return '';
                }           
            }
            var firstChar = deleteNum[0];
            var withoutFirstChar = deleteNum.substr(1);
            if(isNaN(firstChar)){
                return firstChar + rec(withoutFirstChar);
            }else{
                return rec(withoutFirstChar);
            }
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }
    console.log(rec(''));
    console.log(rec("test3yyy33333"));
    console.log(rec("e79898080xampl222e"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the recursion in the following way

```
var reg = new RegExp('[0-9]'); // check for number

function rec(deleteNum) {
    tempNum = ""
    if (deleteNum === "") { 
        return ""; // if string is empty, return
    } else if (reg.test(deleteNum[0])) { // true if deleteNum[0] is a number
        return tempNum += rec(deleteNum.substr(1)) // if current first character is number, skip
    } else {
        return tempNum += deleteNum[0] + rec(deleteNum.substr(1)) // if current first character is not number, add to result and check the rest of the string
    }
}
```

It check character by character using substring from front to back, skipping if the current character is a number. If it is not number, it will add the character to the result, and check the substring of it

Answer (score 0):

`rec` is a function which takes a string as parameter `deleteNum`.

Then the function iterates throughout its length and if the character in any position is digit, it skips it otherwise add it to a string. At the end, it returns that string. Means, it returns the same string without its digit characters.

You can achieve this as below:

```
s = 'test3yyy33333';
t = 'e79898080xampl222e';

s = s.replace(/[0-9]/g, '') or s = [...s].filter(e => isNaN(e)).join('');
t = t.replace(/[0-9]/g, '') or t = [...t].filter(e => isNaN(e)).join('');
```